# WDC Purple (or any Streaming Enabled HDD) as a Desktop Drive

Tags: hard-drive

If I understood correctly, WDC Purples or any other HDD marketed as Surveillance ready drive, supports `Streaming Feature set`,an optional subset of ATA/ATAPI instruction set.

Based on the documents it means, they aim to provide constant time Execution of read/write, **even if in some circumstances for that, they'll sacrifice data integrity**.

Is this behavior is going to be handled in Application level *(Application will check for Streaming feature set support and take advantage of it)*, or it is going to be handled by the Operating System *(the behavior is System-wide)*?

and if its System-Wide, is it possible to use them as normal drives, or it may eventually cause some data corruption in some situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The few posts I could find about this indicate that it's a bad idea to use one of these drives in a PC. However, I'm not convinced that just because the disk supports this ATA command, that it will automatically be invoked. This command has to be issued by the host, i.e. the disk controller, and if your OS doesn't request that feature while performing a read or write, then the hard disk should not favor speed over accuracy.

Comment: thanks for the answer, exactly my thought, unfortunately available information about this topic is contrary, I couldn't reach to a solid conclusion about it.